# Create a new mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know nothing about Emacs Lisp (or any Lisp, for that matter). I want to do something that seems very simple, yet I have had no luck with online guides. I want to create "packet-mode.el" for `.packet` files. I want to do the following:

- Enable C++ mode
- Make `packet` a keyword, while leaving the rest of C++ mode unchanged

```lisp
(define-derived-mode packet-mode fundamental-mode
  (font-lock-add-keywords 'c++-mode `(("packet" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
  (c++-mode))

  (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.packet\\'" . packet-mode)
  (provide 'packet-mode)
```

I've also tried switching the order of the statements in packet mode, but then the C++ highlighting breaks.

I would like `packet` to behave like `struct` in the sense that

```
packet foo {
  int bar;
}
```

is highlighted the same way it would be if `struct` were used in place of `packet`.

Comment: Why not derive directly from `c++-mode`?

Comment: @Thomas, I don't know how to do that. I got the code I have above by copying examples. Could you give me a snippet?

Comment: Try `C-h f define-derived-mode` to understand a bit better what your code is actually doing.

Answer (score 8):

Here is what you need to put into `packet-mode.el`:

```
(defvar packet-mode-font-lock-keywords
  '(("\\<packet\\>" . font-lock-keyword-face)))
(define-derived-mode packet-mode c++-mode "Packet"
  "A major mode to edit GNU ld script files."
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil packet-mode-font-lock-keywords))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.packet\\'" . packet-mode))
(provide 'packet-mode)
```

Place `packet-mode.el` into a directory in your `load-path` and
(optionally) byte compile it.

Now, add `(require 'packet-mode)` into your `.emacs.el`.

Comment: Better move the `font-lock-add-keywords` to within the mode definition, using `nil` as the mode argument: `(define-derived-mode packet-mode c++-mode "Packet" 

(font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("packet" . font-lock-keyword-face))))`

Comment: @Stefan: why? it works like that too. I see it done at top level all over emacs sources.

Comment: @sds when you make an assertion like "all over emacs", you should include some examples.  I'm not 100% of @Stefan's reasons, but the docs `font-lock-add-keywords` suggest his way works for further derived modes, while yours does not.

Comment: @event_jr: see, e.g., `tramp.el` and `dbus.el`.

Comment: @sds: It's OK to use it that way when modifying the behavior of an existing mode, but when you define a new one, it's better to avoid it (even better is to set `font-lock-defaults`, but for quick&dirty hacks `font-lock-add-keywords` is simpler).

Comment: @sds @Stefan: Thanks for the response. packet appears as a keyword when used inline, but for some reason it reverts back to type-face when I use it the way one would use the `struct` or `class` keyword, which unfortunately is the way it gets used. Is there some way to make it behave like `struct`? I apologize for not specifying earlier; I didn't realize there was a difference.