# Emacs Lisp Built-In Indentation Issue with Keywords

Tags: emacs, elisp, keyword, code-formatting, indentation

### Original

---

Say, I have a function like this:

```
(defun my-function ()
  "This is my function."
  :his-keyword xxx
  :her-keyword yyy
  (his-function)
  (her-function))
```

After applying Emacs built-in indentation for Emacs Lisp, I get:

```
(defun my-function ()
  "This is my function."
  :his-keyword xxx
   :her-keyword yyy
    (his-function)
    (her-function))
```

Of course I expected it to stay as it was, so looks like a bug to me. Does anyone know how to intercept this behavior? Or should I file a bug report? I'm on Emacs 24.3.

### Update

---

I figured it out.

I've been extending the `emacs-lisp-mode` with my `elisp-mode` in order to add more syntax highlighting:

```
...

(define-derived-mode elisp-mode
  fundamental-mode
  "EL"
  "A major mode for Emacs Lisp."
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  ...)

(provide 'elisp)
```

And then somewhere:

```
(require 'elisp)

(add-to-list
 'auto-mode-alist
 '("\\.el" . elisp-mode))
```

While `elisp-mode` was loading successfully, it turned out that `emacs-lisp-mode` did not load even though I've put `(emacs-lisp-mode)` into `elisp-mode` initialization (see above).

After changing to:

```
(define-derived-mode elisp-mode
  emacs-lisp-mode
  "EL"
  "A major mode for Emacs Lisp."
  ...)
```

`emacs-lisp-mode` turns on properly and the indentation finally behaves as expected. That was pretty subtle.

Although, the 2nd variant seems more natural and right, can anyone give me a clue why the 1st variant didn't work?

Comment: I'm using 24.2.1 but I'm not seeing this behavior. The `indent-line-function` has the value `lisp-indent-line` while in `emacs-lisp-mode`. Indenting the region containing the code you posted with `indent-region` leaves it unmodified.

Comment: @juan.facorro: Just updated, take a look please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### original question

I cannot reproduce this with `emacs -q` and `emacs-lisp-mode`, so something is wrong with your setup.

You will have to figure out what in your `.emacs` triggers this behavior, and then report the bug (if it contradicts the documented behavior).

### reply to your edit

I think the difference is, more or less, similar to a class inheriting from another class:

```
(defclass c1 (c2))
```

and having a field of that class:

```
(defclass c1 () ((a :type c2)))
```

See also

1. [Defining Derived Modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Derived-Modes.html)
2. [Create new mode in emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885670/create-new-mode-in-emacs)

You might also want to ask a separate question.

Comment: Updated, please take a look.